# Remove related / suggested videos from the end of an embedded YouTube video

Tags: plugin-duktvideos

I'm using the Dukt Videos plugin v1.2.5 on Craft v2.7.2. Is there a way to control or remove the video suggestions that are displayed once my video has played through to the end. Or perhaps have the video restart once it reaches the end ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer isn't specific to the Dukt plugin, but I was going to suggest that passing in the parameter of `rel` with a value of`0` would be the solution. Looking at the docs for YouTube embed shows this is no longer good as of Sept 25, 2018 though:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#rel

Basically, you used to be able to shut off related videos, but YouTube has removed that ability. You're stuck with them if you choose to use YouTube as your video provider.

> After the change [*made on Sept 25, 2018*], you will not be able to disable related videos. Instead, if the rel parameter is set to 0, related videos will come from the same channel as the video that was just played.